# How to catch Dialog Primefaces with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a simple function in a myfile.js:

```
function inclusaoDialog(args, dialog) {
    if (!args.validationFailed) {
        PF(dialog).hide();
    }
}
```

Works fine with(primefaces_5).:

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="inclusaoDialog(args, 'dialogoTipo')" />
```

I'm including in my template:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myfile.js" target="head"/>
```

I'm trying get the dialog with

```
$ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function inclusaoDialog(args, dialog) {
    if (!args.validationFailed) {
        PF(dialog).hide();
    }
});
```

and:

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="inclusaoDialog(args, '#frmTipo\\:dialogoTipo')" />
```

take a look at form:

```
<h:form id="frmCadastro">
   ...
</form>
<h:form id="frmTipo">
    <p:dialog header="Adicionar Tipo de Ocorrência" modal="true"
        widgetVar="dialogoTipo" id="dialogoTipo" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="fade"
        resizable="false" styleClass="cadastro-dialog" position="left,top">
        <h:panelGroup id="inclusaoTipoPanel">
            <p:messages />

            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Tipo" />
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <p:inputText id="novoTipoOcorrencia" size="30" maxlength="45"
                        value="#{ocorrenciaView.tipoOcorrencia.descricao}"
                        required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Informe o novo tipo de Ocorrência." />

                    <p:commandButton value="Incluir"
                            style="display: block; margin-top:5px;"
                            actionListener="#{ocorrenciaView.addTipoOcorrencia}"
                            process="@this :frmTipo:novoTipoOcorrencia"
                            update=":frmCadastro:tipoOcorrencia :frmTipo:inclusaoTipoPanel"
                            oncomplete="inclusaoDialog(args, '#frmTipo\\:dialogoTipo')" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

The primefaces components are collapsing. If I remove

```
[<h:outputScript library="primefaces"...]
```

there are no collapse, but didn't work anyway.

I too did try([W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp)):

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function inclusaoDialog(args, dialog) {
    if (!args.validationFailed) {
        jQuery(dialog).hide();
    }
});
```

I had found how to catch elements of the client-side tree of JSF, but with frameworks like primefaces there are the library conflicts problem. So, how to catch dialog primefaces with jQuery? 
I guess I'm in a pool of mistakes. 
Some Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.execute("Pf('widgetdialogname').hide()")
```

in the `postconstruct` of the managed bean.